# creating array of integers of a given length in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to create an array of integers of length `$lung`. The elements of the array vary from 1 to `$limit` in ascending order. That is, the first element must have value 1, the second value 2 up to `$limit`, after which it starts again from value 1 to `$limit`. This is a draft of my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="limit" select="count(documen('./db/list.xml')/root_list/list"/> 
<xsl:variable name="lung" select="(6) div (./lunghezza)"/>
<xsl:variable name="array" as="xs:integer">
    <Item>1</Item>
    <Item>2</Item>
      ... 
    <Item>$limit</Item>
    <Item>1</Item>
      ...
    <Item>$limit</Item>
</xsl:variable>
```

how to load the array? I am a beginner. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well XSLT does not have `arrays`. With XSLT 1.0 you have node sets, with 2.0 you have sequences (of nodes or atomic values). So with XSLT 2.0 you can create a sequence of integer values with `1 to $limit` e.g. `<xsl:variable name="array" select="1 to $limit, 1 to $limit"/>` creates a sequence of `2 * $limit` values.

[edit]
Perhaps

```
<xsl:variable name="array" select="(for $n in 1 to (xs:integer(ceiling($lung div $limit))) return (1 to $limit))[position() le $lung]"/>
```

is what you want, it creates a sequence of integer values of length `$lung` which contains subsequences ranging from `1 to $limit` where the last subsequence is cut off to ensure the length is exactly `$lung`.

Comment: ok. But if I want that this sequence of integer values has length $lung as I described in the question?

Comment: So far I have not understood how the contents of the sequence and the length are related. With XPath and XSLT 2.0 sequences the length is given by the number of items in the sequence, you can't reserve an array or sequence of a certain length to populate it only with a certain number of items less than the length (as Javascript could do). So please explain if the length is supposed to be `$lung`, where you want to get the content from. Do you want to populate the sequence with subsequences of `1 to $limit`?

Comment: The lenght is supposed to be $lung. I have to create a sequence populated with subsequences of 1 to $limit. e.g if $lung is "6" and $limit is "4", then the sequence have to be "1 2 3 4 1 2". thanks to the availability.

Comment: I think my latest edit does that what you want (by creating `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4` and then cutting off `3 4`).

Comment: using <xsl:variable name="array" select="1 to $limit, 1 to $limit"/>, how can i cutting off 3 4 ? the lenght $lung is supposed "6".

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see your latest edit. It's ok. Thank yuo very much.